# Android : clear focus on edittext when activity starts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've some settings page in my app. Once the activity gets starts directly it focus to edittext and i used following code to clear foucs.

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/RequestFocusLayout"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:layout_width="0px"
     android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

and in java code

```
 RelativeLayout focuslayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RequestFocusLayout);
 focuslayout.requestFocus();
```

The above code is working fine when activity starts at first time and if same activity starts again, automatically edittext get focus.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: is focus coming starting again or coming back from other activity ?

Comment: If Come back from other activity edittext get focused.

Comment: try giving `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in manifest file to that activity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
If Come back from other activity edittext get focused.
```

put these line onStart() or on onReusme()

```
  RelativeLayout focuslayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RequestFocusLayout);
 focuslayout.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the **first focusable view in the activity receives initial focus**.  If that happens to be your `EditText`, it will be initially focused.

If you don't want that, here's your options:

#### Focus *another* view

Programmatically identify what view you do want to give initial focus to.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    findViewById( R.id.yourOtherViewId ).requestFocus();
}
```

#### Make an *earlier view* in your layout *focusable*

If you rather it appears as though "no view has initial focus" you could make the parent view group focusable.  In the following example, I make my `LinearLayout` focusable by setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If your EditText is a child of your RelativeLayout you can use `android:descendantFocusability` to request the focus:

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/RequestFocusLayout"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:layout_width="0px"
     android:layout_height="0px" 
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" 
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the solution shown up in this page but it didn't work. Add this attribute to your activity tag into AndroidManifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Me realy help only `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in my **parent view group**.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to remove the focus in your onStart() method and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout XML file, specify an imeOption on your EditText:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

Next, add an action listener to your EditText in the Activity's java file

```
mYourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            // hide virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mYourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Where mYourEditText is an EditText object

Answer (score 0):

If on starting the Activity it focuses on EditText on the screen.
use

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in the parent containing that EditText. Like if EditText is inside a RelativeLayout use this line in the RelativeLayout.