# mvvmcross MvxBind on actionSend (imeOption action)

Tags: binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

i have an editText like this:

```
    <EditText
        local:MvxBind="Text MyProperty; Click MyCommand"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

I want the command to be triggered by the "enter/action" key on the keyboard. What verb should i use in the binding ? The "Change" verb i currently use triggers on any touch in the control !(

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216585/mvvmcross-change-update-source-trigger-property-of-binding-on-monodroid

Comment: Well not really. He wants something to be fired when focus is lost. I don't :) Do i need a custom converter ? Nothing build in ? If required i'll write it. But if i want to add it as a contribution, in which mvvmcross file/folder should it go ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to implement a "custom binding", then there are 3 types of way to do it:

1. Implement and register a true custom binding
2. Implement a custom control which exposes a custom property to bind to
3. Use an intermediate object which exposes a custom property

---

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19221385/373321 shows a true custom binding.

---

Custom controls which inherit from standard views is discussed in N=18 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com - an example here might be:

```
public class DoneEditText : EditText, TextView.IOnEditorActionListener
{
    public DoneEditText(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public DoneEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public DoneEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
          this.SetOnEditorActionListener(this);
    }

    public ICommand DoneAction { get;set; ]

    #region Implementation of IOnEditorActionListener

    public bool OnEditorAction(TextView v, ImeAction actionId, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (actionId == ImeAction.Done)
        {
            if (DoneAction != null)
                    DoneAction.Execute(v.Text);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

Using an intermediate object for the binding would use a class like:

```
public class DoneActionListener : Java.Lang.Object, TextView.IOnEditorActionListener
{
    public ICommand DoneAction { get; set; }

    public DoneActionListener(TextView v)
    {
          v.SetOnEditorActionListener(this);
   }

    #region Implementation of IOnEditorActionListener

    public bool OnEditorAction(TextView v, ImeAction actionId, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (actionId == ImeAction.Done)
        {
            if (DoneAction != null)
                    DoneAction.Execute(v.Text);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

this could be handled in `OnCreate` using Fluent Binding like:

```
private DoneActionListener _listener;

public override OnCreate(Bundle b)
{
    base.OnCreate(b);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyLayoutId);

    _listener = new DoneActionListener(FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.MyEditId));

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
    set.Bind(_listener).For(v => v.DoneAction).To(vm => vm.TheDoneCommand);
    set.Apply();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a MvxAndroidTargetBinding instead ? With a TargetType of type ICommand ?

Comment: I tried solution 1 and there is no ICommand binding support in custom bindings (in addition to debugging, i also checked the source code). So solution 1 is not a way to do it. Or i missed something. Maybe it is not a MvxAndroidTargetBinding. In this class you never get access to the "ViewModelTarget" property directly. And you can not trigger the ICommand target.