# MvvmCross: Need to change binding mode

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Binding in MvvmCross update text property on every character change.
Is there any way to fire binding after loosing focus for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MvvmCross: change update source trigger property of binding on MonoDroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216585/mvvmcross-change-update-source-trigger-property-of-binding-on-monodroid)

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a custom control so I will juste create an attribute to use this mode.