# Prevent background resize AND prevent auto-focus on activity start

Tags: android, android-edittext

After looking up various questions on stack overflow, I have found that many other people had the following problems:

1. Background gets resized when soft keyboard opens
2. Soft keyboard opens when activity starts

The solution to both of these lies in the `ActivityManifest.xml`.

To prevent the background image from being resized when the soft keyboard opens, you can add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` to the `<activity>` in the manifest.

To prevent the soft keyboard opening when the activity starts, you can add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to the `<activity>` in the manifest.

The fact that one solution requires `stateHidden` and the other requires `stateVisible` means that I cannot use both solutions. I am looking to prevent the soft keyboard from stealing focus on activity start but **also** prevent the soft keyboard from resizing the background when the user *does* decide to focus on the `EditText`.

Is there a viable solution to both of these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fact that one solution requires stateHidden and the other requires
>   stateVisible means that I cannot use both solutions.

Yes. But, you can use `stateHidden|adjustPan`.

Keyboard will not pop up unless user clicks on an `EditText`. And potential changes to your background will be in terms of positioning; scaling of the background will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

If your EditText is wrapped within a parent container, set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` for that container. Basically, make that container receive the initial focus when the activity starts. Take a look at this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157370/android-clear-focus-on-edittext-when-activity-starts)

Comment: I've seen this solution elsewhere before, but it didn't actually work for me. I'm looking for something a little less hacky really.

Answer (score 0):

Is any part of your layout a scrollable container (like ListView)?  If so, try setting `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on that item in your XML layout.

If you have any views which have `android:isScrollContainer="true"`, the layout manager will attempt to resize your layout when the keyboard pops up, regardless of `android:windowSoftInputMode'.

Here's a similar question: [What does android:isScrollContainer do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308247/what-does-androidisscrollcontainer-do)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to fulfill your requirement.

- Just use the below activity tag

  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"

  Or
- Using
    `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` to the    activity tag in the manifest.

Now with your EditText use following `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` with `android:focusable="false"`.