# how to apply adjust_pan on 9patch correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, nine-patch

I have an android dialog with EditText in it.

When the user clicks the EditText, the keyboard is opened

but the dialog is shrink.

The dialog root background is a 9patch

I want it to be cut, meaning its corners won't be rounded but square.

Now, the user might think the shrink dialog is the dialog full size.

I want the keyboard to be laid on the dialog in a way the user will see the dialog is originally larger there are not visible fields.

[image]

I have tried this on the activity that opens the dialog:

```
      mDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: what does *I wan it to be cut, meaning it corners won't be rounded but square.* mean?

Comment: Is your view behind a ScrollView?

Comment: I want it to be cut, meaning its corners won't be rounded but square. 

Now, the user might think the shrink dialog is the dialog full size.

I want the keyboard to be laid on the dialog in a way the user will see the dialog is originally larger there are not visible fields.

Comment: @Elad Benda Can you post your Dialog design layout xml/code?

Comment: I think your problem fixed  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/2677801)

Answer (score 1):

See my similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22463549/335650

> Is any part of your layout a scrollable container (like ListView)? If
>   so, try setting android:isScrollContainer="false" on that item in your
>   XML layout.
>
> If you have any views which have android:isScrollContainer="true", the
>   layout manager will attempt to resize your layout when the keyboard
>   pops up, regardless of `android:windowSoftInputMode'.